# WooCommerce - How to prevent Storefront from loading woocommerce.css after the child theme's stylesheets

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm working on a WooCommerce store using WordPress 4.7, Storefront 2.1.6 and my own Storefront child theme.
But Storefront seems to load a woocommerce.css after my child theme's css (compiled scss) so it overwrites some of my styles. Using '! important' on all these styles seems to be a dirty and unacceptable solution to me. Is there a way to prevent Storefront from loading the woocommerce.css or to load my own styles as the last stylesteet file?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue where I would have needed to use !important on everything.

So I looked at the source code and could see that my stylesheet was loaded before woocommerce's stylesheet.

(I'm using my own child theme and I'm on WP 5.5.1 and WooCommerce 4.5.2)

I found that WooCommerce loads the stylesheet with a hook with priority 10.

> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scripts' ), 10 );

So I changed my stylesheet hook in my functions.php, to priority 11. So it loads later.

> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fitcoach_scripts', 11);

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/

Comment: I already tried this setting but it didn't work. My Safari developer tools still show woocommerce.css on the top of the properties list.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the Storefront theme (as the parent theme) loads it's own version of woocommerce.css so the 'add_filter...' won't work. I really don't know why the parent Storefront theme loads it's css after the child's stylesheets?

Comment: @Mountain I have found the same issue, did you ever find an elegant solution?

Comment: Sadly not. Still there seems to be only the sell-your-soul-!important way :-/